# Отследить закрытие GUI приложения Delphi

Tags: delphi

Можно ли отследить закрытие GUI безоконного приложения Delphi? И как это сделать?
Если мы завершаем процесс через Диспетчер задач то перед закрытием его мы что-то выполняем.

Comment: GUI и _безоконное_ вместе как то странно звучит, или нет?

Comment: Уточните что конкретно вы хотите отследить? Хотите поймать момент завершения чужого приложения/процесса? Или вы хотите словить момент когда ваше приложение принудительно завершают? Может что-то другое?

Answer (score 3):

**Решение для консольного приложения**
(с использованием функций WinAPI)

```
program ConsoleApplication;
uses Windows;

function HandlerRoutine(dwCtrlType: DWORD): BOOL; stdcall;
begin
  if dwCtrlType = CTRL_CLOSE_EVENT then
  begin
    // release memory, show dialogs, etc.
  end;
  HandlerRoutine:=True;
end;

begin
  SetConsoleCtrlHandler(@HandlerRoutine, True) // <-- first line

  // ...
end.
```

Каждый консольный процесс может обрабатывать управляющие сигналы, которые посылаются системой в случае возникновения каких-либо событий: завершение процесса (в том числе принудительное через Диспетчер задач), завершение работы ОС и т.д. Для этого достаточно зарегистрировать собственный обработчик сигналов с помощью функции [`SetConsoleCtrlHandler`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686016(v=vs.85).aspx), передав туда ссылку на сам обработчик.

Возможные типы сигналов, которые могут поступать на вход обработчика:
`CTRL_C_EVENT`, `CTRL_BREAK_EVENT`, `CTRL_CLOSE_EVENT`, `CTRL_LOGOFF_EVENT`, `CTRL_SHUTDOWN_EVENT`. Их подробное описание доступно [в документации](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683242(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: Видел данный пример в сети, но почему то у меня он не работает или я что то не так делаю?((( Сначала вывожу в консоль слово test затем делаю задержку readln. После чего хочу чтобы при закрытии консоли крестиком или через Диспетчер задач появилось бы диалоговое окно, но его нет, вот код:

Comment: program Project2;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses Windows,Dialogs;

function HandlerRoutine(dwCtrlType: DWORD): BOOL; stdcall;
begin
  if dwCtrlType = CTRL_CLOSE_EVENT then
  begin
    showmessage('Меня закрывают');
    // release memory, show dialogs, etc.
  end;
  HandlerRoutine:=True;
end;

begin
writeln('test');
readln;
SetConsoleCtrlHandler(@HandlerRoutine, True);

  // ...
end.

Comment: @Inverse-x оно то и понятно, что не будет работать. Регистрация обработчика, т.е. вызов `SetConsoleCtrlHandler` должен быть выше вашего кода, то есть сразу после `begin`. По-моему, это единственно правильный способ решения данной задачи, я проверял его в IDE Lazarus в том числе отображение диалога при завершении процесса работало корректно.

Comment: А если приложение GUI то как это сделать?

Comment: Чет не работает код закрываю консольное приложение через диспетчер задач и никакого диалогового окна нет, просто все закрывается. Способ не рабочий.

Comment: @Inverse-x по поводу GUI - создайте отдельный вопрос, либо отредактируйте этот, пояснив, в чём заключается ваша задача. Диалогового окна нет потому что вы не добавили его вызов в метод HandlerRoutine (логично же). Кроме того, в вопросе о диалогах ни слова.....